# Redirecting old site to new site (Apache, mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here's what I have in conf file:

```
Alias /test1 /var/www/html/test1
Alias /test2 /var/www/html/test2
Alias /Wiki /var/www/html/mediawiki

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newwiki.samplesite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://newwiki.samplesite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The redirection works. It redirects to `newwiki.samplesite.com` including paths.  But it redirects also the `test1` and `test2` sites. Is there a way to only redirect the `Alias /Wiki`?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newwiki.samplesite.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://newwiki.samplesite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newwiki.samplesite.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Wiki

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://newwiki.samplesite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser's cache once before testing this.

- **Edit**
  Your final config is:

```
Alias /test1 /var/www/html/test1
Alias /test2 /var/www/html/test2
Alias /Wiki /var/www/html/mediawiki

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newwiki.samplesite.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Wiki

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://newwiki.samplesite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223630/discussion-on-answer-by-chi-c-j-rajeeva-lochana-redirecting-old-site-to-new-site).